# How to open FB APP on phone to certain section of the app?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to send a link to the review section on the FB app so someone can leave a review for the business page.

This link opens the businesses app page but would like to structure it so it automatically opens the leave review section.

Any suggestions to ad something to the end of this URL to make this happen?

fb://profile/823389734392895/

http://screencast.com/t/1WLXnkGwTW3z

Much appreciated

Ps.. I would like to do this for Yelp also if possible
yelp:///biz/dc-auto-sales-inc-saint-louis

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. People have found ways to work around this, but it's not guaranteed to work and not officially supported.